# a dominated function for integral

Tags: measure-theory

I have a question :I wil show from dominated convergence theorem that equality :

$\int^\infty_1\frac {log(x)}{x(x-1)} dx =\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}$

I know that  $\frac{1}{x(x-1)}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{k+1}}$ and I should calculate

$\int^\infty_1\frac {log(x)}{x^{k+1}} dx$ but how I can calculate this integral? and wat is the dominated function for above?

Comment: I think you have several $i$s and $k$s exchanged...

Comment: wat do you mean?

Comment: For example you have $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2}$ when I think you mean $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2}$.

Comment: oh,yes. you are right,sorry:)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** For $k \geq 1$, solve $$\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\log(x)}{x^{k+1}} \, dx$$ with integration by parts with $u = \log(x)$ and $dv = x^{-(k+1)}$.

Also, for a dominating function, note that $|\log(x)/x| \leq 1$ for all $x \geq 1$, so that $|\log(x)/x^{k+1}| \leq x^{-k}$. Though, this might not be good enough when $k=1$; however, you're still ok, since for large enough $x$, $|\log(x)/x^{2}| \leq x^{-3/2}$.

Comment: if I solve the integration by parts at the end I have $\frac{-1}{k}x^{-k}.\log(x)$ but that is not equal to$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}$ ??

Comment: If $u = \log(x)$, then $du = 1/x$; if $dv = x^{-k-1}$, then $v = -\frac{1}{k} x^{-k}$. Using integration by parts, you then have 
$$\int_1^{\infty}\log(x)x^{-k-1}\,dx = -\frac{1}{k}\log(x)x^{-k}\big|_1^{\infty} + \frac{1}{k}\int_1^{\infty}x^{-k-1}\,dx$$